# Is there a way to block page creation in Oracle Application Express (APEX)?

Tags: oracle, express, apex

I have several environments, and I should only allow creating pages in the development environment.
In the rest of the environments I must have the possibility to see the session in the developer bar

Answer (score 0):

Apex supports two different type of environments:

- Development Environment: You have access to the toolbar and to the desktop mode
- Runtime environment: Enables you to run production applications, but does not provide a web interface for administration or direct development of these applications.

So, if you want to see the developer bar, Apex must be installed on Development mode and you need to log in with a user who is a developer or an administrator. End users, however, won't be able to see the developer bar no matter which environment you use.

If your users are locally managed by Apex when they access the workspace, the only way for them to not see the developer bar or the desktop mode is that they are end users. If the user can see the desktop mode in the workspace, they can see the developer toolbar.

Comment: This requirement is so that other developers cannot create new pages, not for end users

Comment: if you have Apex installed on development environment ( not runtime ), you can't . As long as they are developers, they have access to the workspace, therefore they can change pages in any application belonging to this workspace

Comment: you would need to create different workspaces for each application in other to isolate them. but that is not recommendable for a development environment, it creates a lot of maintenance for users, because you would have to create users for each single workspace